# Create a new struct inside a while loop when condition changes

Tags: c++

I'm developing a C++ static library with Visual Studio 2015.

I have the following struct:

```
struct ConstellationArea
{
    // Constellation's abbrevation.
    std::string abbrevation;
    // Area's vertices.
    std::vector<std::string> coordinate;

    ConstellationArea(std::string cons) : abbrevation(cons)
    {}
};
```

I use it in a while (note that the method is not ended):

```
vector<ConstellationArea>ConstellationsArea::LoadFile(string filePath)
{
    ifstream constellationsFile;
    vector<ConstellationArea> areas;

    string line;
    ConstellationArea area("");
    string currentConstellation;

    // Check if path is null or empty.
    if (!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
    {
        constellationsFile.open(filePath.c_str(), fstream::in);

        // Check if I can open it...
        if (constellationsFile.good())
        {
            // Read file line by line.
            while (getline(constellationsFile, line))
            {
                vector<string> tokens = split(line, '|');

                if ((currentConstellation.empty()) ||
                    (currentConstellation != tokens[0]))
                {
                    currentConstellation = tokens[0];

                    areas.push_back(area);

                    area(tokens[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return areas;
}
```

I want to create a new `area` object when `tokens[0]` changes but I don't know how to do it.

This statement `area(tokens[0]);` throws the following error:

> call an object of a class type without any conversion function or
>   operator () suitable for the type of function pointer

How can I create a new struct when I need it?

I'm a C# developer and I can't figure out how to do it in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConstellationArea(std::string cons)` is a constructor and must be called during initialization of an object.

So it's legal to have `ConstellationArea area("foo")` because you are initializing the object.

But `area("foo")` is not an [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), actually it's an invocation of `operator()` on the object. In that situation the compiler is looking for `ConstellationArea::operator()(std::string str)` which is not defined.

You must initialize another object and assign it to the variable, eg

```
area = ConstellationArea(tokens[0])
```

This will create another object and then assign the value to it through `ConstellationArea& ConstellationArea::operator=(const ConstellationArea& other)` which is the [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) and it is provided by default.

Comment: Oh, this is very embarrassing. I don't know why I have forgotten this. Maybe, I was a lit bit obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

Reassign the value?

```
area = ConstellationArea(tokens[0]);
```

Comment: Right idea, but needs a bit more explanation of why this is the right idea.

Comment: Simple Problem, Simple answer.